# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'

Tags: python, django

intento obtener el valor de un input type number y guardarlo en una variable en mi vista pero cuando la imprimo me dice 'none'

```
def add_product(request, producto_id):
    cantidad = request.GET.get('cantidad')
    print(" ~ file: views.py ~ line 14 ~ cantidad", cantidad)
    cart = Cart(request)
    producto = Producto.objects.get(id=producto_id)
    cart.add(producto=producto)
    convertido = str(producto_id)
    messages.success(request, 'Producto agregado al carrrito!')


    try:
        urlAnterior = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    except:
        urlAnterior = 'index'

    return redirect(urlAnterior)
```

mi template es el siguiente

```
<form method='GET' class="d-flex justify-content-around ">
 <input name='cantidad' class="form-control mr-2 w-25" type="number" aria-label="Search">
 <a style='background:#D75093;' type="submit" class=" btn text-light" href="{% url 'add_product' object.id %}">Agregar al carrito</a>
</form>
```

si en mi vista cambio

```
cantidad = request.query_params('cantidad')
```

recibo el error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `form` lo ideal es que coloques la dirección de destino en el atributo `action`, en lugar de hacerlo en un enlace.

En lugar del enlace, pon un botón tipo `submit`, que te garantice que el formulario se envía al lugar correcto.

```
<form method='GET' 
  class="d-flex justify-content-around" 
  action="{% url 'add_product' object.id %}">

 <input name='cantidad' class="form-control mr-2 w-25" type="number" aria-label="Search">
 <button 
    style='background:#D75093;' 
    type="submit" class="btn text-light">
    Agregar al carrito
 </button>

</form>
```

Prueba así, a ver qué tal te va.